Applying Excel Custom Template Reorders Series
All I could find is a 2013 post on MS that is locked with no answers.
I've created custom chart templates, and when I apply them to an existing chart, they reorder the series. The templates apply different chart types to different series ... e.g., series 1 & 2 are stacked column, 3,4,5 are stacked area, and 6 is line. Each is colored specifically to represent the type of information and is important to maintain.
I created the templates by setting up the graphs, and then saving them as templates. If I then go in to the exact same graph and apply the new template, the series are all shuffled, destroying my carefully curated and impeccably designed schemes (and shattering my illusions of competence at the same time).
I was hoping to eliminate some VBA that I had been using before I thought of this approach.
I'll note that it happens using any of the four different custom templates I created...
Please share any thoughts/tips/suggestions!!! Thanks.
